# Netbeans GWT can't find and load class GWTCompiler

Tags: gwt, netbeans

I want to make a GWT project with Netbeans. I have just created the project but when I try to compile it but it says that it can't find and load the main class `com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler`.

What should I do?

Comment: did you install gwt plugins..

Comment: I know you want to use Netbeans but it would be so much easier with Eclipse as you can use the Google Plugin for Eclipse: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/